# Quickblox IOS Error "Token is required" while Signing Up or Signing In User

Tags: ios, token, quickblox

I know there are some similiar questions regarding Quickblox returning error "Token is required" but am not able to associate in my case.

Quickblox is returning Error "Token is required" this can make sense if i am requesting after Signing in or signing up.

But why it is giving error while signing in or signing up?

Comment: Try to clean install your app. It could be due to broken cached session after SDK update.

Answer (score 0):

Before Using  QuickBlox SDK you Need to initialize Token

To create session , use below code in you app Delegate

---

```
QBASession *session = [QBASession new];
session.token = @"f23d03bd2341a1f923b7d4c1fbee97af1cd296f2";
```

---

you can update Token if required using Below code

```
[[QBSession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:session updateSessionBlock:{

QBASession *updatedSession = [QBASession new];
session.token = @"new token";

[[QBSession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:updatedSession];

}];
```